# How to pivot a column into a row for sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have budget information that has come to me in the following format (excel)
company, salesrep, week1, week2, week3 and each of the week columns represent a budget amount. The problem is that I am trying to join with a table that has the following columns
weeknumber, company, salesrep, budget amount. So obviously I can't join by by doing weeknumber = week1. How can I structure the join to allow for this. I can go through the entire excel spreadsheet 100k rows and give each row a week number and add a column that shows the budget amount. But that would be quite a bit of work. Is there anyway to accomplish this programmatically? Your help is greatly appreciated. EDIT*** as mentioned by the comments. I have used the following query:

```
SELECT CompanyKey, Subcategory, ItemKey, CustomerKey, SalesRepKey, Pounds
FROM 
(SELECT CompanyKey, Company, CompanyDesc, Subcategory, SubcategoryDesc, 
ItemKey, ItemDesc, CustomerKey, CustomerDesc, SalesRepKey, SalesRep, Wk_1, 
Wk_2, Wk_3, Wk_4, Wk_5, Wk_6, Wk_7, Wk_8, Wk_9, Wk_10, Wk_11, Wk_12, Wk_13, 
Wk_14,
Wk_15, Wk_16, Wk_17, Wk_18, Wk_19, Wk_20, Wk_21, Wk_22, Wk_23, Wk_24, Wk_25, 
Wk_26, Wk_27, Wk_28, Wk_29, Wk_30, Wk_31, Wk_32, Wk_33, Wk_34, Wk_35, Wk_36, 
Wk_37, Wk_38, Wk_39, Wk_40, Wk_41, Wk_42, Wk_43, Wk_44, Wk_45, Wk_46, Wk_47,
Wk_48, Wk_49, Wk_50, Wk_51, Wk_52, Wk_53 FROM Budget_Master) p
UNPIVOT
(Pounds FOR [week] IN 
  (Wk_1, Wk_2, Wk_3, Wk_4, Wk_5, Wk_6, Wk_7, Wk_8, Wk_9, Wk_10, Wk_11, 
Wk_12, Wk_13, Wk_14,
Wk_15, Wk_16, Wk_17, Wk_18, Wk_19, Wk_20, Wk_21, Wk_22, Wk_23, Wk_24, Wk_25, 
Wk_26, Wk_27, Wk_28, Wk_29, Wk_30, Wk_31, Wk_32, Wk_33, Wk_34, Wk_35, Wk_36, 
Wk_37, Wk_38, Wk_39, Wk_40, Wk_41, Wk_42, Wk_43, Wk_44, Wk_45, Wk_46, Wk_47,
Wk_48, Wk_49, Wk_50, Wk_51, Wk_52, Wk_53)
) AS unpvt
```

This gives me a result of the following: [image]

This is going great so far, however I need to add an additional column that says what week # it is. I don't know what for what weeks each row is talking about. It looks like an ASC sort, so I could assume that all rows are weeks 1-53, however I don't want to assume. Is there a way to modify this command to show the week # also?

Comment: How many weeks are you dealing with?  In this case you would use `UNPIVOT` but have to explicitly state the column names you are unpivoting.

Comment: I'm dealing with 53 weeks. So it would be 53 unique columns. I don't mind typing that out, but am unsure of the syntax. it certainly beats the alternative

Comment: use [**UNPIVOT**](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) or [**Dynamic Unpivot**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/passing-column-names-dynamically-to-unpivot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, consider SQL Server's `UNPIVOT`. However, you will need to source from the Excel file, so consider [`OPENROWSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql) if user privileges allow.

```
SELECT company, salesrep, week, budgetamount
FROM 
   (SELECT company, salesrep, week1, week2, week3, ..., week53
   FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                   'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Path\To\Excel\File; HDR=YES; IMEX=1', [SheetName$]) e) p
UNPIVOT
   (budgetamount FOR week IN 
      (week1, week2, week3, ..., week53)
) AS unpvt;
```

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/NAXCH73656)

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. I have actually imported the data from Excel into a table. Keeping the same format. Do you have the syntax in SQL without using the connection to excel?

Comment: @JoeResler ... see demo link at bottom.

Comment: Okay, I have used the syntax provided in the demo link. My problem is the ouptut is now "companykey, subcategory, itemkey, salesrepkey, budgetamount" which is great but it does not tell me which week each row is for. I had 21727 original rows which is now 11517478 because each week column is now a row column so that makes sense. But I need to add a descriptive column to tell me what week is what. Can you help?

Comment: From your edited post, you need to replace *week* with *Wk* in `SELECT` and `FOR` clause. Check again the demo that does output a *week* indicator. Adjust to your actual data.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use UNPIVOT, I find cross apply easier to write and understand.  (also, if you have more than one column to unpivot, it's easier to expand the code

```
CREATE table #Budget
(COMPANY INTEGER NOT NULL,
 REP CHAR(10) NOT  NULL,
 WK1 NUMERIC(9,2) NULL,
 wk2 NUMERIC(9,2) NULL,
 wk3 NUMERIC(9,2) NULL,
wk4 NUMERIC(9,2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_#budget PRIMARY kEY CLUSTERED (Company, REP)
 )
 INSERT INTO #Budget
 (
     COMPANY,
     REP,
     WK1,
     WK2,
     WK3,
     WK4
 )
 VALUES
 (   1, 'ADAM',20,30,40,50),
 (   1, 'JOE',40,50,75,80)

 SELECT bud.COMPANY,
        bud.REP,
        weeks.WkNum,
        weeks.amount
 FROM #Budget bud
 CROSS APPLY 
 (VALUES (1, bud.WK1),
         (2, bud.WK2),
         (3, bud.WK3),
         (4, bud.WK4)
   ) AS weeks(WkNum, amount)
   ORDER BY bud.COMPANY, bud.REP, weeks.WkNum

   DROP TABLE #Budget
```